# interpretation of angle bracket $\langle \circ ; \circ \rangle$ notation appeared in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, dual-spaces

I'm confused around the angle bracket $\langle \circ ; \circ \rangle$ notation appeared in my book, where no definition of that is given. So, it is really nice if someone tell me how to interpret this. The context that the notation is used is as follows:

> **Definition 2.28 (Dual of a linear map)**
> If $A: U \to V$ is a linear map between finite-dimensional vector
> space $U$ and $V$, then the linear map $A^*: V^* \to U^*$ defined by
>
> $\langle A^*(\alpha) ; u \rangle = \langle \alpha; A(u)\rangle, \alpha \in V^*, u \in U$
>
> is a **dual** of $A$.

The book name is `Bullo, Francesco, and Andrew D. Lewis. "Geometric Control of Mechanical Systems." (2005).`

Comment: These brackets are usually reserved for a inner product. It's a positive definite bilinear map, which turns $V$ into an inner product space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\langle A^*(\alpha) ; u \rangle$ is another notation for $A^*(\alpha)(u)$.

It is a notation to highlight duality.